# MongoDB aggregate and project total number of results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using db.collection.aggregate() using the following query below.
I get the results fine, where projected fields are exactly those specified below. I want to also get total number of documents matching this criteria.

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
        { $match: { "age": {"$gte": 20, "$lte": 30}} },
        { $lookup: { from: "photos", localField: "post_id", foreignField: "post_id", as: "photos"} },
        { $project: {
            "title": 1,
            "photos.path": 1,
            "age": 1,
            "city": 1,
            "location": 1,
            "post_id": 1,
            "score": { "$meta": "textScore"}
        } },
        { $sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } },
        { $skip: 0 },
        { $limit: 30 },
    ])
```

After some research I found that I need to add the option below:

```
      { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
```

However, with this added I am now getting this as a response:

```
      { "_id" : null, "count" : 400 }
```

The count is correct, but the fields that I want to project are no longer there. Is there a way to get the count AND the fields I want to project in one result? Or do I have to run two separate queries, one for count and one for fields I want to project?

Comment: The latter has _nothing_ in common with the former. And the latter should return exactly 1 result, with `count` being the total number of documents. If it does not, you have some more serious problems in your setup.

Comment: Thanks Markus. I understand second has nothing to do with the first. I edited the question so that it makes more sense. the second part is what I am adding to the first. The intent there is to get total number of documents matching the same criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, the grouped documents can be accessed with [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)

Comment: That worked thank you. Do you know know how I would add score as well? I am trying it just like other fields: { ..., score: "$score"} but no luck

Comment: After $project, score is ordinary field and can be accessed just like others. If something "wrong" happening, the fault is probably before obtaining score itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your aggregation Pipeline

{ $group: { _id:
{"title":"$title","age":"$age","city":"$city","location":"$location","post_id":"$post_id","score":"$score"}, count: { $sum: 1 } } })